# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ntcore in java.library.path?

Tags: java, eclipse

Im trying to run some basic code in a gazebosim, the project builds fine but once it connects to gazebo i get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ntcore in java.library.path"

I have found the file ntcore.so and sepcified its location with -Djava'library.path

```
target name="simulate" depends="jar-for-simulation">
<sequential>
  <echo>[simulate] You may now run Gazebo and your DriverStation</echo>
    <echo>[simulate] Running Code.</echo>
    <java jar="${simulation.dist.jar}" fork="true">
      <jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path={/home/alex/wpilib/java/current/lib/native/lib/libntcore.so}" />
  </java>
</sequential>
```

Any ideas? This is driving me crazy

Output of the console:

```
Buildfile: /home/alex/workspace/TestRobo/build.xml
Trying to override old definition of task classloader
compile:
 [echo] [athena-compile] Compiling src with classpath=/home/alex/wpilib/java/current/lib/WPILib.jar:/home/alex/wpilib/java/current/lib/NetworkTables.jar:/home/alex/wpilib/java/current/lib/opencv.jar:/home/alex/wpilib/java/current/lib/cscore.jar to build
jar-for-simulation:
 [echo] [jar-for-simulation] Building jar.
  [jar] Building jar: /home/alex/workspace/TestRobo/dist/FRCUserProgramSim.jar
simulate:
 [echo] [simulate] You may now run Gazebo and your DriverStation
 [echo] [simulate] Running Code.
 [java] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
 [java] resources = |sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@f0a63f|
 [java] platform: /Linux/i386/
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ntcore in java.library.path
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
 [java]     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
 [java]     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
 [java]     at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.networktables.NetworkTablesJNI.<clinit>(NetworkTablesJNI.java:60)
 [java]     at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.networktables.NetworkTable.initialize(NetworkTable.java:44)
 [java]     at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.networktables.NetworkTable.getTable(NetworkTable.java:176)
 [java]     at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.RobotBase.<init>(RobotBase.java:58)
 [java]     at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.SampleRobot.<init>(SampleRobot.java:31)
 [java]     at org.usfirst.frc.team420.robot.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:29)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
 [java]     at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.RobotBase.main(RobotBase.java:190)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `java.library.path` to the directory the library is located, not the library itself.

```
<jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=/home/alex/wpilib/java/current/lib/native/lib" />
```

(Im not sure if the { } are required or problematic?)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error can be the following;

**Cause:**

The **PATH** variable does not include a directory which contains the native libraries required for your Java classes to function.

**Workaround:**

On both Windows or /and the Unix platforms, add your dependencies to the PATH variable. Follow [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t49342.html) article for further information

OR

You could add `-Djava.library.path` as a VM argument in your ECLIPSE launch configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem not too long ago. The way I solved this was by compiling [ntcore](https://github.com/wpilibsuite/ntcore) from source using [Gradle.](https://gradle.org)

The instructions on how to do this are included in the README of ntcore.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just mixed up the names in the header and in the method:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_JINICall_doMultiply (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, int);JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_JNICall_doMultiply ( JNIEnv * jenv, jobject jobj, jint val1, jint val){ return val1 * val2;}
```

Comment: _JINICall_ != JNICall_